# TKinter Text/Entry widget prints strange chars when pressing F1 (OSX)

Tags: python, tkinter

Pressing the F1 key (or other function keys like F5, F6, etc.) when the focus is on the text widget, puts these strange question mark chars on the text widget.

What is the best way to disable printing these chars?

[image]

I can bind to the KeyPress event to detect them and avoid printing it, but was wondering if there is a better way of doing the same. 
All works fine on Windows 10 and Linux, I'm only seeing this issue on Mac OSX. 
Using Python 3.7 on Mac Mojave.

Here's my workaround:

```
self.function_key_sym_re = re.compile(r'^F\d+$')
self.editor_text.bind("<KeyPress>", self.on_editor_key_press)

. . . 
def on_editor_key_press(self, event):            
    if self.function_key_sym_re.match(event.keysym): 
        return "break"
```

Answer (score 1):

On Mac the F-Keys are bound to system functions by default. To use the F-Keys you need to press the "Fn"-Key and the F-Key.

Solves that the question mark input?

Comment: Yes, when using the 'Fn' key and F1 it does not print these strange chars... So - do you suggest that it is expected to see these chars if pressing the function key without Fn? (I'm working mostly on Windows so not sure on Mac known behavior...)

Comment: I am not complete sure about this, but I assume that this behavior on mac is correct and expected.